# \left. and \right. delimiter is not working

Tags: brackets

I wanted to make one long equation over two lines, since the right hand side was very big, and tried to surround the entire right hand side with {} brackets, but failed to do so with the following code:
'''

```
    \begin{align}
    A &= - B \left\{ -C - D\left[ E \right.  \notag \\
    &\left. + F\right] \right\}
    \end{align} 
    '''
```

Executing this LaTex code does not output the correct parentheses for the right hand side, and there is one missing } symbol.
How do I successfully display another } symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need 2 `\right.` statements toward the end of line 1 and 2 `\left.` statements near the beginning of line 2. This is because matching `\left`-`\right` pairs are not allowed to be interrupted by line breaks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    A &=    B \left\{ C + D\left[ E  \right.\right.   \\
      &\quad  \left.  \left. {}+ F   \right]\right\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: or simpler and better here, remove all the `\left` and `\right`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - The OP did mention something about the real document having "one long equation over two lines", with "the right hand side [being] very big". So I'll give him/her the benefit of the doubt that the `\left` and `right` sizing directives aren't superfluous. :-) Of course, it may well be the case that there are better alternatives to `\left` and `\right` in the "big equation" as well.

Comment: @Mico    This is exactly what I was looking for! I did not know how \left. and \right. works, but now I got the idea that these correspond to each \left-\right pair instead of taking care of all the \left-\right pair at once. 

And yes, the equation was pretty big, but I wanted to simplify the appearance to make things easier. 

Thank you so much!

Comment: @ArkanineOkhotsk - You're most welcome. May I suggest that you post a new query, with the complete "big equation", and ask if there may be better alternatives to nested `\left`-`\right` sizing directives for the equation at hand?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `\left` and `\right` can fail if one line contains larger items than the other. In that case sizing manually with `\bigl` , `\biggr` etc. works better.

Comment: @IanThompson - The concern you mention is actually one of the reasons for why I wrote "it may well be the case that there are better alternatives to \left and \right" and subsequently encouraged the OP to post a new query, to show the real "big equation". (Besides using manual sizing directives, another fix would be to include suitable `\vphantom` directives in the row with the relatively small "big" (tall?, deep?) items.)